# Oracle JDBC connection for AWS Federated Athena

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, federated

Team,

We are planning to connect Oracle database from AWS Athena Federated. Is there any custom connector is available or any steps to create a new connector.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check on below. Athena has a Oracle connector that can be used to federate queries across S3 and oracle .

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/query-your-oracle-database-using-athena-federated-query-and-join-with-data-in-your-amazon-s3-data-lake/

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.